# MacOS Terminal alternative/replacement like SecureCRT SSH Client (Mac OS X)?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, terminal

I understand Terminal.app is the way most people use for telnet/ssh connections on the Mac, but I'm wondering if there is something like SecureCRT on the Mac.

Kind of an all in one solution which would support modem, telnet and ssh connections under one roof and which offers a good address book to just dial/connect to my various hosts with one (or a few clicks).  Scripting would be nice too.  (I've seen iTerm but it sort of just doesn't click, also scripting is Apple Script which I find very confusing.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never used SecureCRT myself, but from what you describe, the [ZOC Terminal Emulator](http://www.emtec.com/zoc/index.html) should fit your bill (it's commercial though, but as I understand, so is SecureCRT).  Some guy on Versiontracker commented, it was the [closest thing to SecureCRT for the Mac](http://www.versiontracker.com/php/feedback/article.php?story=20090413073731297).

It uses REXX as a scripting language (a bit somewhere between basic and perl), is centered around a host directory (it can be split in sections and each can have subfolders) and connects for telnet, ssh, rlogin, modem and also has a local shell for the Mac (although for local work I'm still mostly opening the native Terminal).  The list of emulations looks fairly complete to me, at least I've never missed one and there are some that I never had any need for.  It's available for Windows too if that's of any interest.

Screenshots are [here](http://www.emtec.com/zoc/screenshotsmac.html).

Comment: The screenshots look good.  Besides modem, does it connect via null modem to devices (I occasionally need to configure cisco gear and the only program I found that does it on the Mac so far seems to be from ancient times and is plain ugly.).

Comment: Yes, it should do that too.  A friend of mine uses ZOC for just that since he bought himself a Macbook/Pro to impress his clients (he has written some fancy scripts that make ZOC do the work him).

Comment: Tried it and it's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

[SecureCRT](http://vandyke.com/products/securecrt/index.html) for Mac OS X was released on October 21, 2010:

Answer (score 1):

[iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home) came a long way since the iTerm of the old days with helpful features like full-screen, split-pane, paste history, etc.  (see [features](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/features)).